# Using Wordpress Outside of Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, foreach, woocommerce

I am trying to access the products Woocommerce stores in the database outside of Wordpress. I have an external php page (index) that I want to display the products on using a foreach method. I'm trying to use WP/WC as the backend area of the site so my client can add products, but the theme I made for him already is just a HTML5 theme. I really want to find a workaround that would allow me to add the products to this page without converting the entire theme.

My folder setup is as follows: 
hallsgems/ 
hallsgems/wordpress

I've added this code to my index.php file trying to connect it to the WP system:

```
<?php
$location = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];

include ($location . 'wordpress/wp-config.php');
include ($location . 'wordpress/wp-load.php');
include ($location . 'wordpress/wp-includes/pluggable.php');
include ($location . 'wordpress/wp-includes/shortcodes.php');
?>
```

The main goal of trying to connect WP is so I can generate one of these for every product in the database:

```
<!-- Begin Stone -->
      <div class="item col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 hover-overlay" data-groups='["peridot"]'>
        <a href="#!" class="open-overlay-window heading" data-overlay-window=".item-overlay-9">
          <img alt="Project 1" src="/peridot.png" />
          <div class="overlay background-90-a">
            <div class="hidden-xs">
              <p class="title heading-a">Image</p>
              <p class="text-center heading-a"><strong>Excepteur sint lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</strong></p>
              <p class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-picture-o heading-a"></i></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
```

What changes to the above code would I need to be able to access WC data using PHP, and can you provide me with a basic for each example if possible?

Thank you

Comment: my understanding of wp-load was that it automatically loaded the config values, a bunch of core wp stuff, and your theme's functions.php file which would also load your shortcodes and other theme specific stuff.  Why do you include config and shortcode files?  Have you tried without?

Comment: I started with just wp-load, but it didn't do what I needed so I just started adding other main files, which, still did nothing.

Comment: maybe try doing one core wp function.  Like query your 3 most recent post names using the wp query function.  if you can get that to work and still can't get woo commerce stuff working, it sounds plugin specific.  Maybe they have a solution...a lot of plugins just require you to include some specific plugin files manually

Comment: You should just need wp-load. I do this in one of my plugins with just wp-load, and I'm able to access anything from the WP installation, database, plugins, functions, globals, whatever.

Comment: I have my code simplified to just the wp-load file, but shortcodes are still not working; can someone provide a basic loop or function that would display the WC products?

Comment: To get WooCommerce data outside of WooCommerce seems like the purpose of the [WooCommerce API](http://woothemes.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/)

Comment: Why not just use the API?